# Unable to connect between Router and PC with crossover cable in Cisco Packet Tracer Student

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

I just started my CCNA course. I tried to connect the router to the PC with a crossover cable, but it always shows that the protocol is down. Any configuration I might have missed?

[image: router to pc]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

I did the same here. Check the cable again and try to ping the gateway. It's working for me.